# Is there any way to load data in parallel when gpu is computing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am using keras with tensorflow for deep learning. I work with slightly large dataset (images), so I couldn't load the whole dataset at once, instead, I load on batches of 8000 images, and use model.fit() for training (code snippet below).

```
for epochs in range(50): # number of epochs
    for i in range(num_batches): # 5 batches with 8000 images each
        #### load the data here (train, val)
        history_train = model.fit(train_image, train_gt, batch_size=16, epochs=1, verbose=1, shuffle=False, validation_data=(val_image,val_gt))
        if history_train.history['val_loss'][0] < total_val_loss:
            model.save_weights(weights_file)
            total_val_loss = history_train.history['val_loss'][0]
```

Certainly not an efficient way. It takes a lot time to load a batch (of 8000 images), than the time to learn (running time of each epoch). Is there any better way in which I could do this? or any other way to optimize it?  Can I load data (for next epoch) in parallel when computing (GPU) is getting done so I can save on the loading time?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this by using `fit_generator` instead of `fit` and passing the arguments `use_multiprocessing=True` and `workers=n` (where n is the number of worker threads). For loading your dataset, you will need to make a generator method that yields each batch. It should look something like this (I'm assuming that your input dataset is a 4D array of shape (num_images, height, width, channels), so adapt as necessary) :

```
def generator(dataset_x, dataset_y):
    while True:
        for i in range(num_batches):
            yield dataset_x[i*8000:(i+1)*8000, :, :, :], dataset_y[i*8000:(i+1)*8000, :]
```

Note that this will return batches of size 8000 -- you might need to cut it down more with another loop that returns batch sizes of, say, 16. 
And for training the model:

```
history_train = model.fit_generator(generator=generator, steps_per_epoch=5, epochs=50, use_multiprocessing=True, workers=16, validation_data=val_generator, validation_steps=5)
```

You might want to make 2 generators: one for training data and one for validation data. Also, Keras might give you a warning about using multiprocessing with multiple workers -- you should make your generators thread-safe by encapsulating them or by using keras.utils.Sequence (more info about this in Keras documentation).

Comment: this didn't work for me ( didn't speed up the loading of the data ).

Answer (score 0):

I have dataset of 40GB so I can load all images in memory. Therefore, I have to load batch wise. generator here splits who dataset into 'N' number of batches but it need to have images loaded in memory.

Is there any method in keras to do something similar to following tensorflow code:

```
path_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(input_paths, shuffle= False)
paths, contents = reader.read(path_queue)
inputs = decode(contents)
input_batch = tf.train.batch([inputs], batch_size=2)
```

I am using this method to serialize inputs in tensorflow but I don't know how to achieve this task in Keras.

Comment: how is this an answer? but since you already asked - yes - https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly.html